# Public/private key to encrypt AES session key

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I've been working on an encryption/decryption program. I am using AES.
What I am struggling with is, removing the `string password` and create a AES session key. This AES session key is what I actually want to use to encrypt and decrypt the data with. Then use the private or public key to encrypt this AES session key and stored locally (for example purposes).

Below is the coding which is currently fully working to encrypt and decrypt data with a plain text string:

Coding so far:

```
// password to encrypt the file
String password = "p@sswordDataNoW";

// salt is used for encoding
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
FileOutputStream saltOutFile = new FileOutputStream("salt.enc");
saltOutFile.write(salt);
saltOutFile.close();

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536,
                128);
SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

//padding AES encryption
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();

// iv adds randomness to the text and just makes the mechanism more
// secure
// used while initializing the cipher
// file to store the iv
FileOutputStream ivOutFile = new FileOutputStream("iv.enc");
byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
ivOutFile.write(iv);
ivOutFile.close();

//file encryption
byte[] input = new byte[64];
int bytesRead;

while ((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1) {
        byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
        if (output != null)
                outFile.write(output);
}

byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
if (output != null)
        outFile.write(output);

inFile.close();
outFile.flush();
outFile.close();
```

Please could someone help me out, in terms of changing the `string password`to a session key that is generated. Then encrypt this session key with either the public or private key and stored on the local system.

I have tried many different ways and every time it has no worked out.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava, I appreciate your response. I fully understand the working of public and private keys. The reason why I stated it as above is because it all depends on the user of the system. This is because if only the user is permitted or has the access role for the level of file then it will encrypt the session key with the public key so that only the can access or decrypt it. Then using the private key is use to encrypt the session key if multiple can access such and there is need to signatures to be involved. But thanks again for your response, it is still appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AES key consists of either 16, 24 or 32 bytes and is supposed to look like random noise. The user is never going to see it. So, you can generate it securely:

```
SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
byte[] aesKey = new byte[16];
r.nextBytes(aesKey);
```

Here I generated a 16 byte key. You should use 24 or 32 byte for higher security, but only if you installed the Unlimited Strength policy files for your JRE/JDK.

Now, the remaining encryption is easy:

```
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
// everything else as before
```

---

Separately from that you can *encrypt* `aesKey` with your *public key*. If you "encrypt" with a private key, you're not protecting the AES key from spying on. "Encrypting with a private key" is called signing and that data is not confidential.

Comment: Thank you for your response. so basically if I am understanding it correct: I can remove the 'String password' and place your secure random 'coding above'. Then encrypt the aeskey with the private key and store such. Thanks again.

Comment: No! You can remove all the PBE, PBKDF2 and SecretKeyFactory stuff, but you need to encrypt **`aesKey` with a public key**, otherwise you don't get confidentiality which is the only thing that AES itself provides.

Comment: Thank you again for clarity. I have been able to get that working. Is there an particular way that I should encrypt the aeskey using the public key. I know that the public key will need to be read in using the inputstream , however, if there a suitable way of doing such. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: You haven't described your application in detail, so I can't say where it would be best to keep your public key and what else you need. However, I can say that you need to use proper padding if you encrypt with RSA. Currently, the best padding is OAEP. Also, you can further improve your AES encryption by adding authentication, so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.